# Maven не может найти JDK

Tags: linux, maven

Возникла довольно странная ситуация при попытке установить Apache Maven на  Xubuntu 16.04.2.

Переменные окружения были заданы правкой файла /etc/profile.d/jdk.sh. Были добавлены следующие строки :

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_131/bin/java
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export M2_HOME=/usr/maven/apache-maven-3.5.0
export PATH=$M2_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Так, логично заключить, что $JAVA_HOME указывает на JDK.

Тем не менее, при попытке вызвать

```
mvn -version
```

возвращается

```
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE
```

Я не совсем понимаю, как исправить сложившуюся ситуацию.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**JAVA_HOME** должна указывать на директорию в которой есть директория **bin**. У вас она указывает на исполняемый файл.

Вот так будет правильно

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_131
```